# Unable to use QUERY in google sheets when referencing cell as a value

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a spreadsheet in google sheets that tries to do the following.

1. Retrieves a table by scraping a website.
2. Uses a query within that table to retrieve a specific value in the table.
3. Uses an existing cell in the spreadsheet to determine the value to match.

You can see the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IW2JasDKbB-khLtYTYRmFVwfq3D3hAUJEWPLxRPJ8IA/edit?usp=sharing). Cell D2 is the one in question. It attempts to use the C2 value to build a query. It doesn't work for some reason. I believe I have the correct syntax, but I'm not sure. Directly below in Cell D3 is the same formula with the value directly entered rather than referring to the cell.

I am getting an error that says "query completed with an empty output", which doesn't make sense to me when it works with the value directly inputted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, I was using the syntax incorrectly. The correct formula goes like this.

=query(importhtml(B2,"table",1),"select Col4 where Col8 ="&C2,1)

I imagine it was throwing an error because the second & symbol would lead it to believe that more text was coming and there was none.